# Converting a string automatically into a link to a pdf document

Tags: string, python-3.x, pdf, tkinter

I've done some looking around in here and on the internet and it doesnt seem super obvious, but my question is can python using tkinter be used to automatically convert a text string into a link that loads a pdf from a certain direction

e.g. data '12345 Issue A' pops up in a text widget and is automatically converted to a link that when clicked opens up a pdf document.

Can this or can it not be done ?

In this case I'm wanting to be able to click 1931-125, 699-126 and 1851-127 and have each open up a pdf file of the same name. This is being used in a manufacturing environment and allows an assembler to click the fields and have all the documents they need to build a certain item

[image]

Comment: That depends on your definition of "automatically". You'll have to write the code that does it, but it's certainly possible for the text widget to have links that open up other programs.

Comment: Thats totally fine, I just didnt want to go down this path if it wasnt possible or the modules werent available....I'm a newbie so aiming for something that achievable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off to apply formatting to parts of a Text widget you will need to understand about [tags](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-tag.html), in most cases you can probably just use the phrase of the link (ABC123) just remember that:

> The name of a tag can be any string that does not contain white space or periods.

once you have a tag for the link there are two parts:

1. Formatting the tag to look and react like a link.
2. Applying the tag to the phrases in text.

The first one is really simple if you just want it to be blue and underlined and respond to being clicked:

```
def format_link(text_widget,tag,command):
    text_widget.tag_config(tag,foreground="blue",underline=1)
    text_widget.tag_bind(tag,"<Button-1>",command)#remember that the command will need to take an event argument
```

Although this could get more complicated if you want the cursor to change when hovering over or colour to change after clicking etc.

---

The second part is to apply this tag to the text *automatically* which I'm assuming means parse the text after it is inserted into the widget.  This is also very simple by putting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464813/explain-tkinter-text-search-method/19466754#19466754) in a loop so that it checks for every occurrence of the phrase:

```
def apply_tag(text_widget,phrase,tag,regexp=False):
    countVar = tk.IntVar(text_widge)
    idx = "1.0"
    while idx:
        idx = text_widget.search(phrase,idx, stopindex = "end",
                                 count = countVar, regexp = regexp)
        if idx:
            end_idx = "%s + %sc" %(idx, countVar.get())
            text_widget.tag_add(tag, idx, end_idx)
            idx = end_idx
```

---

Then all that is left is defining the way to open the file in another program and then calling the two above functions, using `os.system("open"...)` to open files it could be as simple as:

```
def make_link(text,phrase,file_to_open):
    def callback(event=None):
        os.system("open %r"%file_to_open)#there are better ways of handling this
    apply_tag(text,phrase,phrase)#uses phrase as tag
    format_link(text,phrase,callback)
```

Although you might want to look at [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python) or [it's duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054434/how-can-i-open-files-in-external-programs-in-python) for alternatives for opening files.

---

after inserting the text into the widget, assuming you have some sort of list of phrases to turn into links, you can just loop over the phrases and call `make_link` for each one:

```
phrases = {"1931-125", "699-126", "1851-127"}

for s in phrases:
    make_link(TEXT_W, s, s+".pdf") #make a link to same name with .pdf added to end.
```

Comment: does this method allow you (with code modification) convert the text to a clickable whereby the text name remains unchanged but it now points to a specific location and file name?  For example my 'result' text widget gives me ABC123, I want this to now display as ABC123 (but is now clickable) and when clicked it looks in a certain directory on the computer with the file ABC123 which in this case would be ABC.pdf - hope this makes sense

Comment: I re-answered the question, and will try to avoid unnecessarily long or complicated answers in the future.

Comment: I know this is a reply to an old question (been away for a bit with our 2nd child), I just wanted to verify that the above would work with multiple lines in a text widget that each have different text. I've added a screen shot of my program that may assist with what I'm trying to achieve. The first line 1931-125 I wish to tag, and have it associated with a pdf file called the same name that resides in a directory, then I wish to repeat with the second line 699-126 etc etc. The aim is a person can click each series of numbers & have the different pdf documents open.

Comment: absolutely, just call `make_link` for each link to make, I added a bit at the end if it helps.

Comment: Thank you :) with your phrases code - phrases = {"1931-125", "699-126", "1851-127"}, can strings be used instead of hardcoded numbers ? The reason being 'job x' will have different drawings to 'job y' and if I have a few hundred jobs each with different drawings its a lot of maintainance. I was envisaging that when my csv line is read in (with all relevent drawing info) those drawing numbers are stored as strings and then used as the phrase - if thats the best way to go about it.

Comment: "assuming you have some sort of list of phrases to turn into links" @LesM76, I had no information on where the strings to turn into links was coming from until you only **just** mentioned csv, if you can extract the list of -should be links- from the csv then that is what you use.