# Python: open file in network drive

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use a script to open a file inside a network drive using python. The script is given below:

```
import os
import subprocess

file_path = r"O:\XXXX\test.xls"
subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True)
```

The network drive requires sign in but I always by default sign it the moment I on the computer. Also, using a os.listdir(folderpath) has no problem going into the network drive and listing all the files in the directory containing the file.

Tried some suggestions from similar posts but they don't work.

I am using Python 2.7, and Windows.

**UPDATE**:

No error was prompted after executing the script.

I am trying to open an Excel file. The script works to open Excel in other folders within the computer, but just not within the network drive.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Just updated the post. There was no error prompted. Thanks!

Comment: You should not open arbitrary files with `Popen`. `Popen` should be used to execute executables.

Comment: Okay I think I managed to understand ops problem - you want the file to open in excel? Is that right? Please don't keep us guessing...

Comment: Yes, sorry about being unclear. Can you advise how to open it if not by Popen?

Comment: do you want `os.startfile(filepath)`?

Comment: related: [How can I open files in external programs in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15054434/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian your suggestion work! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question (why the behavior for the network drive and other folders is different *if it is indeed the case). If `os.startfile()` works for you; you could post it as an answer. [It is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Yea that's true, but at least it works for my work now. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @J.F. Sebastian's suggestion. replacing `subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True)` with `os.startfile(filepath)` works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you

```
import subprocess

file_path = r"X:\dir\excelfile.xlsx"
#~ also this works
#~ file_path = r"\\server\dir\excelfile.xlsx"
subprocess.call(file_path,shell = True)
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work too. J.F Sebastian's one using os.startfile(filepath) works though. Thanks anyway!