# python - automatically launch a text file created in the program

Tags: python-3.x

I did the search but i couldn't find any help, apologies if i my question is duplicate.

i am writing the code with python 3.6 and in windows environment.in my code, i opened a text file, write the data and close the file.

```
self.fileName = 'file path'
self.log_file = open(self.fileName, 'w')
self.log_file.write('Write results')
self.lof_file.close()
```

Instead of the user goes to file path and click to open it, i want to launch the file automatically after python save it.

how do i do that? please help

EDIT:

```
os.startfile(filepath=self.fileName)
```

command is working fine, but its opening with default program which is Notepad, how to open the file with specific program, for example, Notepad++

Comment: what do you mean by "launch the file"? in text editor?

Comment: yes, i am creating the file as *.txt     want to open it with Notepad or Notepad++

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, how your file should be launched? in what text editor? it is OS-dependent

Comment: i am using Windows platform, instead of default program i want to open it with another program.

Comment: Have a look at the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, especially `subprocess.Popen`.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the command line way of doing it, you can use the `os` module as follows:

```
import os
self.file = 'file path'
self.log_file = open(self.fileName, 'w')
self.log_file.write('Write results')
self.lof_file.close()
os.system('gedit <file_path>')    # for ubuntu, gedit is generally present
```

For Windows, you can use:

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\\Users\\RandomUser\\Documents\\test.txt')
```

Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055133/9332801

Comment: Sorry to ask you, can you explain a bit please, i am using windows

Comment: @mortuzahasan Updated my answer.