# Open file in IDLE through python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

**How would I open a specific file in IDLE through a python script?**

I understand that an app could be opened through subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('C:\\program.exe')
```

But I can't figure out how to make it open a file.

If it helps, this:

```
import os.path
import sys

# Enable running IDLE with idlelib in a non-standard location.
# This was once used to run development versions of IDLE.
# Because PEP 434 declared idle.py a public interface,
# removal should require deprecation.

idlelib_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
if idlelib_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, idlelib_dir)

from idlelib.pyshell import main
main()
```

also opens IDLE. I checked, and main() does not take any parameters such as files to open.

I am using Windows 10 with Python 3.6.4.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054434/how-can-i-open-files-in-external-programs-in-python

Comment: Try using run() or Popen ... get the stdout and stderr etc.

Comment: Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054434/how-can-i-open-files-in-external-programs-in-python did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to open any python file through IDLE

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["idle.exe", path_to_file])
# ... do other things while idle is running
returncode = p.wait() # wait for notepad to exit
```

OR:

```
import subprocess
import os

subprocess.call([path_to_idle, path_to_file])
```

You can also use these methods to open any file with any installed app ([How can I open files in external programs in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054434/how-can-i-open-files-in-external-programs-in-python))

Comment: The existence of 'idle.exe' is installation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

One can run IDLE from a command line on any platform with `<python> -m idlelib <IDLE args>`, where `<python>` could be 'python', 'python3', or something line 'py -3.8', depending on the platform.  `<IDLE args>` are defined in the "Command line usage" subsection of the [IDLE doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html), also available within IDLE as Help => IDLE Help.

A possible 'IDLE arg' is the path of a file to be opened in an editor window.  Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, which can be changed with the 'cd' command.  A working command line can used quoted or turned into a list for a [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) or [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) call.  In Python code, the working directory is changed with `os.chdir('newdir')`.

Comment: Could you provide a python example?

Comment: @Andoo I just replaced quotes with backticks and added links, so my answer should be much clearer now.

Comment: I still don't see an actual example