# how to open multiple songs using an external application in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, operating-system, external

in my code I need to play a playlist of songs were downloaded to the device so I need to know how to open songs in external apps
in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054434/how-can-i-open-files-in-external-programs-in-python) i found how to open a single song as `os.runfile(fileName)` worked fine for me with single songs .. so is there is some thins like `os.runfiles` which obliviously isn't available

Answer (score 0):

Don't use os.
Use

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys

externalApp = 'vlc'
command = shlex.split('{} ~/Videos/*mp4'.format(externalApp))
subprocess.run(command)
```

That is if you're using linux. If not, modify command accordingly.

Comment: unfortunately i'm using windows and i keep getting file not found error .. can you explain how can i modify the command please ?

Comment: I think you just need to make path to input file look windows-like, like so: "C:/Users/Username/Videos/someVideo.mp4", or wherever it is you keep your media files.