# I want to open another application with python, that does not close when the script ends

Tags: python

I am making a program that is making .docx files for the user, and i want my script to open the file when it is done. I then want the script to end, but when the script ends the .docx file closes immediately.

To open the file i use:
`proc=os.popen(fileName)`

Any help would be great.

I am using python 3.10 and windows 10.

Comment: Does this help* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447603/how-to-kill-a-python-child-process-created-with-subprocess-check-output-when-t

Comment: `popen()` is exactly the _wrong_ thing to use for this: It sets up a FIFO between your parent process and the child's stdout. In doing so, it makes the child more dependent on the parent than it would be if you used almost anything else.

Comment: thanks @Charles, what would u suggest i use?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `subprocess` module. I found a similar question to your and I do encourage reading all answers and specially @jfs answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055133/5203248

I will quote the important part from his answer to how to do it with `subprocess`

> If you want to run a specific application then you could use subprocess module e.g.,  Popen() allows to start a program without waiting for it to complete:
>
> ```
> import subprocess
>
> p = subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe", fileName])
> # ... do other things while notepad is running
> returncode = p.wait() # wait for notepad to exit
> ```
>
> There are many ways to use the subprocess module to run programs e.g., subprocess.check_call(command) blocks until the command finishes and raises an exception if the command finishes with a nonzero exit code.